# How to sort array inside collection record in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have a collection of students, each with a record that looks like the following and I want to sort the `scores` array in descending order of `score`.

what does that incantation look like on the mongo shell?

```
> db.students.find({'_id': 1}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 60.06045071030959
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 52.79790691903873
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 71.76133439165544
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 34.85718117893772
                }
        ]
}
```

I'm trying this incantation....

```
 doc = db.students.find()

 for (_id,score) in doc.scores:
     print _id,score
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You will need to manipulate the embedded array in your application code or using the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2.

Example aggregation in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.students.aggregate(
    // Initial document match (uses index, if a suitable one is available)
    { $match: {
        _id : 1
    }},

    // Expand the scores array into a stream of documents
    { $unwind: '$scores' },

    // Filter to 'homework' scores 
    { $match: {
        'scores.type': 'homework'
    }},

    // Sort in descending order
    { $sort: {
        'scores.score': -1
    }}
)
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
            "scores" : {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 71.76133439165544
            }
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "Aurelia Menendez",
            "scores" : {
                "type" : "homework",
                "score" : 34.85718117893772
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You can change the end of the aggregation pipeline to sort in ascending order (so the lowest comes first) and limit to 1 document: ` { $sort: { 'scores.score': 1 }}, { $limit : 1 }`

Comment: Issue of duplicate data, you are going to repeat name in every object.So if i have 20 fields in upper level  , then should i repeat ?

Comment: @PrabjotSingh I'm not entirely clear what your question is, but instead of discussing in the comments you should post a new question with an example of your document structure, desired output, and version of MongoDB server/driver.

Comment: I agree with @PrabjotSingh scores be returned as an embedded array? Like the question suggests.

Comment: @F.O.O This question is 6.5 years old and there are different options now depending on your version of MongoDB server. Please post a new question with details relevant to your environment and the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: However it is not possible to re-wind without disturbing the sorted order.

Answer (score 17):

Starting in `Mongo 5.2`, it's the exact use case for the new [`$sortArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#mongodb-expression-exp.-sortArray) aggregation operator:

```
// {
//   name: "Aurelia Menendez",
//   scores: [
//     { type: "exam",     score: 60.06 }
//     { type: "quiz",     score: 52.79 }
//     { type: "homework", score: 71.76 }
//     { type: "homework", score: 34.85 }
//   ]
// }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: {
    scores: {
      $sortArray: {
        input: "$scores",
        sortBy: { score: -1 }
      }
    }
  }}
])
// {
//   name: "Aurelia Menendez",
//   scores: [
//     { type: "homework", score: 71.76 },
//     { type: "exam",     score: 60.06 },
//     { type: "quiz",     score: 52.79 },
//     { type: "homework", score: 34.85 }
//   ]
// }
```

---

This:

- sorts (`$sortArray`) the `scores` array (`input: "$scores"`)
- by applying a sort on `score`s (`sortBy: { score: -1 }`)
- without having to apply a combination of expensive `$unwind`, `$sort` and `$group` stages

Comment: What if it's an array only. e.g [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @RyanAquino [sort-an-array-of-integers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/#sort-an-array-of-integers)

Comment: This one is **the only** correct answer to given question. All other answer are using different input data or update existing data or remove scores rather than sort the array or use a different language despite it asked for mongo shell.

Answer (score 8):

Since this question can be managed in different ways i want to say that another solution is "insert and sort", in this way you will get the Ordered array at the moment you will made a Find().

Consider this data:

```
{
   "_id" : 5,
   "quizzes" : [
      { "wk": 1, "score" : 10 },
      { "wk": 2, "score" : 8 },
      { "wk": 3, "score" : 5 },
      { "wk": 4, "score" : 6 }
   ]
}
```

Here we will update the Document, make the Sort.

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 5 },
   {
     $push: {
       quizzes: {
          $each: [ { wk: 5, score: 8 }, { wk: 6, score: 7 }, { wk: 7, score: 6 } ],
          $sort: { score: -1 },
          $slice: 3 // keep the first 3 values
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Result is:

```
{
  "_id" : 5,
  "quizzes" : [
     { "wk" : 1, "score" : 10 },
     { "wk" : 2, "score" : 8 },
     { "wk" : 5, "score" : 8 }
  ]
}
```

Documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort

Comment: can we use $each on stored array field?

Comment: This will update existing data, in the question it asks only to **query** the data.

Answer (score 5):

That's how we could solve this with JS and mongo console:

```
db.students.find({"scores.type": "homework"}).forEach(
  function(s){
    var sortedScores = s.scores.sort(
      function(a, b){
        return a.score<b.score && a.type=="homework";
      }
    );
    var lowestHomeworkScore = sortedScores[sortedScores.length-1].score;
    db.students.update({_id: s._id},{$pull: {scores: {score: lowestHomeworkScore}}}, {multi: true});
  })
```

Comment: Dude? You spoiled the fun.

Comment: Does the `{"scores.type": "homework"}` filter expression inside find() achieve something?

Comment: @TreefishZhang Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @AlexanderPanasyuk What did it achieve? -Did it filter out some students?

Comment: This will update existing data, in the question it asks only to **query** the data. Running a loop (with `forEach`) and update the documents one-by-one will usually let to poor performance. `{multi: true}` does not make sense when you filter on primary key `_id`

Answer (score 3):

In order to sort array, follow these steps:

**1)** use unwind to iterate through array

**2)** sort array

**3)** use group to merge objects of array into one array

**4)** then project other fields

Query

```
db.taskDetails.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$counter_offer"},
    {$match:{_id:ObjectId('5bfbc0f9ac2a73278459efc1')}},
    {$sort:{"counter_offer.Counter_offer_Amount":1}},
   {$unwind:"$counter_offer"},
   {"$group" : {_id:"$_id",
    counter_offer:{ $push: "$counter_offer" },
    "task_name": { "$first": "$task_name"},
    "task_status": { "$first": "$task_status"},
    "task_location": { "$first": "$task_location"},
}}

]).pretty()
```

Comment: Opposed to `$addToSet`, using `$push` preserves the order of the array, sorted in the preceding step.

Comment: Worked as asked. But I don't have unwind again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the java code which can be used to find out the lowest score in the array and remove it.

```
public class sortArrayInsideDocument{
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    DB db = client.getDB("school");
    DBCollection lines = db.getCollection("students");
    DBCursor cursor = lines.find();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject cur = cursor.next();
            BasicDBList dbObjectList = (BasicDBList) cur.get("scores");
            Double lowestScore = new Double(0);
            BasicDBObject dbObject = null;
            for (Object doc : dbObjectList) {
                BasicDBObject basicDBObject = (BasicDBObject) doc;
                if (basicDBObject.get("type").equals("homework")) {
                    Double latestScore = (Double) basicDBObject
                            .get("score");
                    if (lowestScore.compareTo(Double.valueOf(0)) == 0) {
                        lowestScore = latestScore;
                        dbObject = basicDBObject;

                    } else if (lowestScore.compareTo(latestScore) > 0) {
                        lowestScore = latestScore;
                        dbObject = basicDBObject;
                    }
                }
            }
            // remove the lowest score here.
            System.out.println("object to be removed : " + dbObject + ":"
                    + dbObjectList.remove(dbObject));
            // update the collection
            lines.update(new BasicDBObject("_id", cur.get("_id")), cur,
                    true, false);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice! Good example...With java 8 we can minimize the compare part.

Comment: @Vel How does removing the `dbObject` from `dbObjectList`, remove from the `cur` DBObject? What is the link between `cur` and `dbObjectList`?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to guess, but anyway, try not cheat with mongo university courses because you won't understand basics then.

```
db.students.find({}).forEach(function(student){ 

    var minHomeworkScore,  
        scoresObjects = student.scores,
        homeworkArray = scoresObjects.map(
            function(obj){
                return obj.score;
            }
        ); 

    minHomeworkScore = Math.min.apply(Math, homeworkArray);

    scoresObjects.forEach(function(scoreObject){ 
        if(scoreObject.score === minHomeworkScore){ 
            scoresObjects.splice(scoresObjects.indexOf(minHomeworkScore), 1); 
        } 
    });

    printjson(scoresObjects);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Order Title and Array title also and return whole collection data Collection name is **menu**

```
[
            {
                "_id": "5f27c5132160a22f005fd50d",
                "title": "Gift By Category",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Ethnic Gift Items",
                        "s": "/gift?by=Category&name=Ethnic"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Novelty Gift Items",
                        "link": "/gift?by=Category&name=Novelty"
                    }
                ],
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "_id": "5f2752fc2160a22f005fd50b",
                "title": "Gift By Occasion",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Gifts for Diwali",
                        "link": "/gift-for-diwali" 
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Gifts for Ganesh Chathurthi",
                        "link": "/gift-for-ganesh-chaturthi",
                    }
                ],
                
                "active": true
            }
    ]
```

**Query as below**

```
let menuList  = await  Menu.aggregate([
                { 
                    $unwind: '$children'
                }, 
                {
                    $sort:{"children.title":1}
                },
                {   
                    $group : { _id : "$_id",
                        root: { $mergeObjects: '$$ROOT' },   
                        children: { $push: "$children" } 
                    } 
                },
                {
                    $replaceRoot: {
                        newRoot: {
                            $mergeObjects: ['$root', '$$ROOT']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        root: 0 
                    }
                },
                { 
                    $match: {
                                $and:[{'active':true}],
                            }
                },
                {
                    $sort:{"title":1}
                }                  
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before question was edited it was

> I want to sort the 'type': 'homework' scores in descending order.

This means, the array has to be filtered and sorted. In more recent version of MongoDB you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         scores: {
            $sortArray: {
               input: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$scores",
                     cond: { $eq: ["$$this.type", "homework"] }
                  }
               },
               sortBy: { score: -1 }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are doing `M101P: MongoDB for Developers` where homework 3.1 is to remove the lower one from two homework scores. Since aggregations were not taught up to that point you can do something like this:

```
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db = conn.school
students = db.students

for student_data in students.find():
    smaller_homework_score_seq = None
    smaller_homework_score_val = None
    for score_seq, score_data in enumerate(student_data['scores']):
        if score_data['type'] == 'homework':
            if smaller_homework_score_seq is None or smaller_homework_score_val > score_data['score']:
                smaller_homework_score_seq = score_seq
                smaller_homework_score_val = score_data['score']
    students.update({'_id': student_data['_id']}, {'$pop': {'scores': smaller_homework_score_seq}})
```

Comment: OP was for the mongo js shell, but this is a super clean Python example!

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach using pyMongo, the Python driver to MongoDB:

```
import pymongo


conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')

def remove_lowest_hw():
    db = conn.school
    students = db.students

    # first sort scores in ascending order
    students.update_many({}, {'$push':{'scores':{'$each':[], '$sort':{'score': 1}}}})

    # then collect the lowest homework score for each student via projection
    cursor = students.find({}, {'scores':{'$elemMatch':{'type':'homework'}}})

    # iterate over each student, trimming each of the lowest homework score
    for stu in cursor:
        students.update({'_id':stu['_id']}, {'$pull':{'scores':{'score':stu['scores'][0]['score']}}})

remove_lowest_hw()

conn.close()
```

Answer (score -2):

the answer of @Stennie is fine, maybe a `$group` operator would be useful to keep the original document, without exploding it in many documents (one by score).

I just add **another solution when using javascript for your application**.

if you query only one document, it's sometimes easier to sort the embedded array by JS, instead of doing an aggregate.
When your document has a lot of fields, it's even better than using `$push` operator, otherwise you've to push all the fields one by one, or use `$$ROOT` operator (am I wrong ?)

My example code uses **Mongoose.js** :
Suppose you have initialized you Students model.

```
// Sorting
function compare(a, b) {
  return a.score - b.score;
}

Students.findById('1', function(err, foundDocument){
  foundDocument.scores = foundDocument.scores.sort(compare);
  
  // do what you want here...
  // foundModel keeps all its fields
});
```

Answer (score -2):

this work for me, it is a little rough code but the results of the lowest tasks for each student are correct.

```
var scores_homework = []
db.students.find({"scores.type": "homework"}).forEach(
  function(s){
    s.scores.forEach(
        function(ss){
            if(ss.type=="homework"){
                ss.student_id = s._id
                scores_homework.push(ss)
            }
        }
    )
})
for(i = 0; i < scores_homework.length; i++)
{
    var b = i+1;
    var ss1 = scores_homework[i];
    var ss2 = scores_homework[b];
    var lowest_score = {};
    if(ss1.score > ss2.score){
        lowest_score.type = ss2.type;
        lowest_score.score = ss2.score;
        db.students.update({_id: ss2.student_id},{$pull: {scores: {score: lowest_score.score}}});
    }else if(ss1.score < ss2.score){
        lowest_score.type = ss1.type;
        lowest_score.score = ss1.score;
        db.students.update({_id: ss1.student_id},{$pull: {scores: {score: lowest_score.score}}});
    }else{
        lowest_score.type = ss1.type;
        lowest_score.score = ss1.score;
        db.students.update({_id: ss1.student_id},{$pull: {scores: {score: lowest_score.score}}});
    }
    i++
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I have implemented in Java (Have kept it simple so that it's easier to understand) -

Approach :

1. Get *scores* array from *student* collection
2. Get all *score* values from scores array where *type == homework*
3. Sort the score values so that lowest becomes 1st element [score.get(0)]
4. Then, loop through the main *scores* and create new copy of scores array while skipping elements where *type == homework && score == scores.get(0)*
5. Finally, update the new scores array to student document.

Below is working Java code:

```
    public void removeLowestScore(){
    //Create mongo client and database connection and get collection
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost");
    MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("school");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("students");


    FindIterable<Document> docs = collection.find();
    for (Document document : docs) {

        //Get scores array
        ArrayList<Document> scores = document.get("scores", ArrayList.class);           

        //Create a list of scores where type = homework
        List<Double> homeworkScores = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (Document score : scores) {
            if(score.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("homework")){
                homeworkScores.add(score.getDouble("score"));   
            }
        }

        //sort homework scores
        Collections.sort(homeworkScores);

        //Create a new list to update into student collection
        List<Document> newScoresArray = new ArrayList<Document>();
        Document scoreDoc = null;

        //Below loop populates new score array with eliminating lowest score of "type" = "homework"
        for (Document score : scores) {
            if(score.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("homework") && homeworkScores.get(0) == score.getDouble("score")){                  
                    continue;                       
                }else{
                    scoreDoc = new Document("type",score.getString("type"));
                    scoreDoc.append("score",score.getDouble("score"));
                    newScoresArray.add(scoreDoc);
                }               
            }           

        //Update the scores array for every student using student _id
        collection.updateOne(Filters.eq("_id", document.getInteger("_id")), new Document("$set",new Document("scores",newScoresArray)));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Certainly it's late, but I just want to contribute my own solution on Mongo Shell:

```
var students = db.getCollection('students').find({});
for(i = 0 ; i < students.length(); i++) {
    var scores = students[i].scores;
    var tmp = [];
    var min = -1 ;
    var valueTmp = {};
    for(j = 0 ; j < scores.length; j++) {        
        if(scores[j].type != 'homework') {
            tmp.push(scores[j]);
        } else {
            if (min == -1) {
                min = scores[j].score;
                valueTmp = scores[j];
            } else {
                if (min > scores[j].score) {
                    min = scores[j].score;
                    tmp.push(valueTmp);
                    valueTmp = scores[j];
                } else {
                    tmp.push(scores[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    db.students.updateOne({_id:students[i]._id},
                            {$set:{scores:tmp}});
}
```

Answer (score -3):

sort by the score can be simple like:

```
db.students.find({_id:137}).sort({score:-1}).pretty()
```

but you need to find the one for type:homework ...

Comment: $sort used in conjunction with $push and $each will do at the mongo shell: `db.students.updateMany({}, {'$push':{'scores':{'$each':[], '$sort':{'score': 1}}}})` per [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/)

Answer (score -5):

it should be something like this:

```
db.students.find().sort(scores: ({"score":-1}));
```

Comment: If this is written in mongoshell this isn't valid, neither will it do the job he asks for. Correctly it should be db.students.find().sort({"scores.score":-1}) but this doesn't sorts anything (at least nothing I can see), especially not the scores array within the student. As far as I know, you need to manually iterate over those array entries and do the sorting, mongo won't do it.

Comment: also philnate is correct....this does not bring the desired result in mongo shell...thanks for the attempt.

Comment: I'm a python and mongodb noob...this link leads to an answer in PHP...I'm looking for a solution in python or in mongo shell.