# sort query for array structure in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have a document having array structure in MongoDB.
How can I sort the array element in ascending order?

The below is the Input:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sanjay",
    "address": "Odisha",
    "shoes": [
        {
            "brand": "puma",
            "size": "10"
        },
        {
            "brand": "bata",
            "size": "11"
        },
        {
            "brand": "rebook",
            "size": "9"
        },
        {
            "brand": "adidas",
            "size": "7"
        },
        {
            "brand": "bata",
            "size": "8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help me to get a query to sort my all array element in ascending order of the key "size"?

The below is the required output.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sanjay",
    "address": "Odisha",
    "shoes": [
        {
            "brand": "adidas",
            "size": "7"
        },
        {
            "brand": "bata",
            "size": "8"
        },
        {
            "brand": "rebook",
            "size": "9"
        },
        {
            "brand": "puma",
            "size": "10"
        },
        {
            "brand": "bata",
            "size": "11"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could you please help me to find out the exact query?

Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: This post answers your questions. You need to use the aggregation feature to unwind the array and then sort it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

**In your sample data, `shoes.size` is a string type**. Before sorting, you need to change it to Int. You can use following query to do it.

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(data) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < data.shoes.length; ii++) {
    printjson(data._id);
    print(data.shoes[ii].size);
    db.shoe.update({
        "_id": data._id,
        "shoes.size": data.shoes[ii].size
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "shoes.$.size": parseInt(data.shoes[ii].size)
        }
    });
    }
});
```

After changing it use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to sort `shoes` array by following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$shoes"
}, {
    $sort: {
    "shoes.size": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "shoes": {
        "$push": "$shoes"
    },
    "name": {
        $first: "$name"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

**Edit**

If you want to select for specific `brand` then add criteria in `match` condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$shoes"
}, {
    $match: {
    "shoes.brand": "bata"
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
    "shoes.size": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "shoes": {
        "$push": "$shoes"
    },
    "name": {
        $first: "$name"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Vishwas could you please tell how could I find only matching array element in mongoDB. for example I want only array element in shoes whose brand is "bata".

Comment: @SanjayakumarSahu Is it usefull to you?