# MongoDB mongooperations java sort subdocument

Tags: java, mongodb

I have database collection like this

```
Fruit class

_iD

country

listNameFruit

    Mango ,
    Tomato,
    Apple
```

So I have class named `Fruit` and `FruitName` , inside `Fruit.class` I have `list<FruitName>` , so I want to get my `Fruit` and list of `FruitName` sort by ascending

Here's my code to get the collection

```
MongoOperations mongoOps;

Query query = ???
mongoOps.findOne(query, Fruit.class);
```

I want to get my fruit data but I want the `listNameFruit` is sort by ascending , what should i write in the query so i can get my list sort by ascending ?

Comment: What are you actually searching for? You've said `findOne` so presumably you're looking for a specific fruit, is that by ID, by country, or just the first value you can find?

Comment: Also, I don't think that MongoDB allows you to sort the values in an array in a straightforward fashion - they are returned in the same order they are stored in the database. You can [change this order when writing to the list](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort), but when querying you might need to look at the Aggregation Framework. An example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb