# Selective field in output from Array of Documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and still trying to learn basics.

Here is my document in MOongoDB in which I am facing some issue.

```
{
        "_id" : 19,
        "name" : "Gisela Levin",
        "scores" : [
                {
                        "type" : "exam",
                        "score" : 44.51211101958831
                },
                {
                        "type" : "quiz",
                        "score" : 0.6578497966368002
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 93.36341655949683
                },
                {
                        "type" : "homework",
                        "score" : 49.43132782777443
                }
        ]
}
```

Now, I am firing a query something like this:to find the scores of student where type is homework in sorted order and only the homework score needs to be found.

```
db.students.find({"name":"Gisela Levin","scores.type":"homework"},{"_id":1,"scores.score":1});
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting output only the score corresponding to homework in sorted order and not others. (i.e. I dont want score for exam and quiz in the output but only for homework in sorted order).
I am trying to use projection but I am kinda struck with no forward path.

Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort array inside collection record in mongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb)

Comment: because is a question from MongoDB University dev course.