# Sorting objects in array within mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I've seen this question all over google/SO/mongo docs, and I've tried to implement the solution, but it's not working for me.  I have the following test database:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4ab167db9acd913ce6e07"),
    "state" : "HelloWorld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "124"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And I want to sort by the "guid" element of items.**  Running the sort commands yields:

```
> db.test.find().sort( {"items.guid" : 1}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4ab167db9acd913ce6e07"),
    "state" : "HelloWorld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "124"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I sort by the "guid" element, so that the returned output of "items" is the 123, 123, and 124 guids (essentially move the child elements of "items" so that they're sorted by "guid")?

**EDIT**: I've also tried to use the `$orderby` command, doesn't accomplish what I want:

```
> db.test.find({ $query : {}, $orderby: {'items.guid' : 1}  }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4ab167db9acd913ce6e07"),
    "state" : "HelloWorld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "124"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If all your `guid` are of 3 digits then sorting is possible using `aggregate` command else it will be difficult because they are not numerical, they are string.

Comment: have a look at this: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

Comment: @dikesh: could you please provide an example of the aggregate command that'll accomplish the sorting?

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn: I tried the orderby, didn't work (see edit)...

Comment: have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Comment: Thanks, the aggregate command worked.  It's so not-intuitive, but maybe that's just because I'm new to mongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it can be done using `aggregate`

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind : '$items'
    },
    {
        $sort : {'items.guid' : 1}
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$_id',
            state : {$first : '$state'},
            items : {
                $push : {'guid' : '$items.guid'}
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

This is the output from this command.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b4ab167db9acd913ce6e07"),
    "state" : "HelloWorld",
    "items" : [
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "123"
        },
        {
            "guid" : "124"
        }
    ]
}
```