# How sort array of objects in collection MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am using node.js and MongoDB. I have collection with next schema:

```
var project = new Schema({
head:{
    head_task: String,
    userID: String
},
access_users: {
    type : Array ,
    "default" : []},
context_task: [{
            from_name: String,
            status: Boolean,
            task: String,
            created_task: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
             }
        }],
created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }});
```

How I can get docs sorting by field context_task.created_task by DESC.
I think that I have to using aggregate query

```
db.tasks.aggregate({$match :{"_id":ObjectId("590e2d7d4d4a5e0b647d0835")}},
 {$sort: {"context_task.created_task": -1}}).pretty();
```

but sorting doesn't work. 
Maybe I have to sort Data on client?
Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Comment: does it work when you use .find()? db.tasks.find({ "_id":ObjectId("590e2d7d4d4a5e0b647d0835") }, { sort: "context_task.created_task": 1 }) ?

Comment: @Dinesh, Thanks, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**$sort** is deprecated. You need to use sort function with find.

```
db.tasks.find({_id : "590e2d7d4d4a5e0b647d0835" })
.sort({context_task.created_task : 1})
.limit(1)
```

Comment: Thank, but it doesn't work for me. I am using next query and this working.
 `db.tasks.aggregate({$match: { "_id":ObjectId("592e87cf7a91b810209235cc")}},{ $unwind: '$context_task' },{$sort: {'context_task.created_task': -1}}).pretty();`