# How to update to order the elements of an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

DB Sample...

```
 { "code" : "2156",
    "trades" : [ 
        {
            "close" : 78000,
            "date" : "2017.11.08"
        }, 
        {
            "close" : 25300,
            "date" : "2017.08.07"
        }, 
        {
            "close" : 74900,
            "date" : "2017.11.07"
        }
    ] 
 },
  { "code" : "2158",
    "trades" : [ 
        {
            "close" : 79000,
            "date" : "2017.11.08"
        }, 
        {
            "close" : 24300,
            "date" : "2017.08.07"
        }, 
        {
            "close" : 71900,
            "date" : "2017.11.07"
        }
    ] 
 }
```

Above is my exist mongodb data sample. What I want to do is arrange objects in `trades` by **date asc**. So It should be arrange like this

```
    "trades" : [ 
        {
            "close" : 24300,
            "date" : "2017.08.07"

        }, 
        {
            "close" : 71900,
            "date" : "2017.11.07"
        }, 
        {
            "close" : 79000,
            "date" : "2017.11.08"
        }
    ]
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm using Node.js and Mongoose. 
I already check this article :

[how to sort array inside collection record in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb)

But it looks like not ordering db itself, it just query db to certain conditions, right? Is there a way to ordering db itself?

Comment: You can go with the option given by @Jim, provided you convert string dates to ISODate

Comment: Try `db.collection_name.update(    { },    { $push: { trades: { $each: [ ], $sort:{date:1}} } }, {multi: true } )`

Comment: @Avij Can you give me a hint? I couldn't figure it out

Comment: @Veeram Unfortunately that's not working, `WriteResult : nMatched: 0, nUpserted: 0, nModified: 0`

Comment: Can you update post to include query you have tried ?

Comment: @Veeram I am sorry, it's working well. I did with mistake. Can you post your comment as an answer, ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Veeram You saved me, you must genius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) modifier to order the elements in an array. `multi:true` to apply updates to multiple documents.

Something like

```
db.collection_name.update( { }, { $push: { trades: { $each: [ ], $sort:{date:1}} } }, {multi: true } )
```

Answer (score 0):

"Ordering the DB" is really not necessary.  If you create indexes on the fields you want to query by, MongoDB will effectively "order" these for you.

Here's MongoDB's instructions on creating indexes:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

Since you tagged this with node.js, I assume you're using mongoose.  In which case you can add {index: true} to your schema definition.

Mongoose's instructions on defining indexes for schemas:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.4.x/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: Can you give me a hint? I couldn't figure it out

Comment: Since you didn't provide any example source, I can only point you at the documentation....