# MongoDB filter objects array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following record in my DB [Simplified to what matters to the question], I was wondering if there is a way where I can select all records with Type = 1, customerID = "Customer 1" and sort by transDateTime ASC? Thanks.

```
{
    type: "1",
    notes: "bla bla",
    transactions : [ 
        {
            "customerID" : "Customer 1",
            "transDateTime" : ISODate("2017-09-10T18:54:41.983Z")
        }, 
        {
            "transDateTime" : ISODate("2017-08-10T18:54:41.983Z")
        },
        {
            "customerID" : "Customer 1",
            "transDateTime" : ISODate("2017-02-10T11:54:41.983Z")
        }    
    ],
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort array inside collection record in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can access sub-fields via a dot notation

```
find({ "type": "1", "transactions.customerID": "Customer 1" }).sort({ "transactions.transDateTime": 1  })
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document/#document-dot-notation