# Mongodb aggregate embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following database in mongodb:

```
{
 "notebook": 
  {"Year20162017": 
    {"Cards": [
      {"Card": {
        "Number": 1,
        "Player": {
            "Code": "a",
            "Team": {
                "Name": "ABC"
            }
        }
    }},
    {"Card": {
        "Number": 18,
        "Player": {
            "Code": "c",
            "Team": {
                "Name": "GHI"
            }
        }
    }},
    {"Card": {
        "Number": 35,
        "Player": {
            "Code": "b",
            "Team": {
                "Name": "DEF"
            }
        }
    }}
]}}}
```

I need to sort by the number of each card, so I tryed to do it using aggregations:

```
db.cromos1617.aggregate([
{$unwind: {"notebook.Year20162017.Cards"}},
{$sort: {"notebook.Year20172017.Cards.Card.Number": 1}}
])
```

First I used unwind to separate the array of Cards, then I sorted the elements by the number of each card, but it didn't worked well, it gave me:

```
2018-01-04T18:44:09.593+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):2:41
```

How it is done properly?

Comment: Couple of things incorrect here. `$unwind` takes the string reference($) and for string reference no document({}) is allowed. Try `db.cromos1617.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$notebook.Year20162017.Cards"},
{$sort: {"notebook.Year20172017.Cards.Card.Number": 1}}
])`

Comment: It didn't worked, I changed the numbers randomly and when I apllied that it returned me the original database disorderly

Comment: Seems typo in sort stage. it should be Year20162017

Comment: yeah it's working right, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort array inside collection record in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb)