# MongoDB sorting by date as type String

Tags: mongodb

Can someone help me with the query for sorting an array by date in ascending order?
I have tried the below query but the sorting is not happening as expected,

```
db.getCollection(xyz).aggregate([{

       $match: {
          "_id":{$in:[{"a" : "NA","b" : "HXYZ","c" : "12345","d" : "AA"}]}
                     }
                   },{
                       $sort: {'bal.date': 1}
                   },

                   { $project: {
            balances: { $slice: ["$bal",2]} 

                        }

             }

                  ])
```

My collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "a" : "NA",
        "b" : "HXYZ",
        "c" : "12345",
        "d" : "AA"
    },


       "bal" : [
     {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-08-02"

    },

    {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-08-01"


    },
     {
            "type" : "E",
            "date" : "2015-07-07"


    }

 ]
 }
```

Please help me what is the problem in the above query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your sample collection...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have added the sample data.

Comment: Even with the string format it is working for me... Check it https://mongoplayground.net/p/qpf7kM8EUCL... I think your query syntax is incorrect here

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Can you post the query which your using here.Am unable to access the link provided above

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Comment: @Veeram thanks for response but can't v sort the bal array without unwind

Comment: No its not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `$match` with `$sort` stage

Correct syntax to used aggregation pipeline stages

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "_id": {
      "$eq": {
        "a": "NA",
        "b": "HXYZ",
        "c": "12345",
        "d": "AA"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$bal" },
  { "$sort": { "bal.date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "bal": {
      "$push": "$bal"
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Updated the answer have a look

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're  saving the date as String, the **sort()** function will sort the dates as **Strings** which will not give you the order you're expecting.

You can either run a script that will convert the **bal.date** field to Date() format and then sort() will work automatically, or you can do the converting + sorting server side.

Comment: the collection I fixed and the date is stored as string only in collection and I cant perform convertion and sorting at server side so can yu help me with alternative way

Comment: The date must be stored as Date() if you want to sort it automatically using MongoDB sort() function.

First have a backup to your database and have an update on your collection that changes the bal.date into new Date(bal.date)

Comment: I will just hit the collection and the collection is maintained by other team.So  no way of upgrading as well :(

Comment: You can get a copy or a mock in as your local database, and test the update the collection. And provide the script for the other team and ask them to backup the database and update he collection.