# how to sort array of objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My MongoDB document structure:

```
 _id:ObjectId("12345")
    hai:Array
    0:Object
    designation:"software"
    1:Object
    designation:"hardware"
    2:Object
    designation:"Core"
```

I need to sort the designation in hai array.
I tried like this, but not working

```
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("12345")}).sort(hai:-1)
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("12345")}).sort(hai.designation:-1)
```

Can anyone please help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `unwind` array first then you can able to sort data.

ref link : [Sort array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13455095/8612835)

Answer (score 0):

The sort function expects an object like this (note the brackets in sort):

```
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("12345")}).sort({hai:-1})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({_id:ObjectId("12345")}).sort({"hai.designation":-1})
```

Also note if your sort is on a nested object then you need to use quotes around your key.

Aside: If you dont use the pipeline i.e. complex queries then you don't need to use unwind.

Comment: I think the requirement is not sorting the documents, but sorting a field inside document.