# mongoose $sort doesn't work with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my query,

```
db.getCollection("docs").aggregate(
[
    {$match: {
        userId: ObjectId('55d833edd29d5903005'),
    }},
    {
        $project: { 
            fieldOne: 1,
        },
    },
    {$group: {_id: null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$fieldOne"}}},
    {$sort: {"uniqueValues.fieldOne": -1}},
]
)
```

The above query display results in random order without my $sort condition. I also used with `exec()` callback still the same

**{$sort: {"uniqueValues.fieldOne": -1}} and {$sort: {"fieldOne": -1}}** both doesn't show correct result.. Any idea?

**UPDATE 1:**
**Output, each time when I run the order changes**

```
{ 
    "_id" : null, 
    "uniqueValues" : [
        "5674-1", 
        "5621-1", 
        "5445-3", 
        "5572-1", 
        "5490-1", 
        "5537-1",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data in the question present in the document ?

Comment: @stud3nt added please check

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb

Comment: @stud3nt might be but still stuck combining with ``group``

Comment: @overflow : You no longer have `fieldOne` in your document, So `{"uniqueValues.fieldOne": -1}` won't work !! Also you finally have a single document with an array `uniqueValues`, then here what you would like to make an order of ? Is that the values in array ? then `$sort` won't work here, if that's the case you need to move your `$sort` stage up above, Please provide sample docs someone can provide a query if needed..