# How to sort array inside of document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a event document with an array of ten people in it, each one with one score, i want to return the same event but with the people sorted by their score.

The json looks something like this:

```
"events": [
        {
            "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4a",
            "place": "Belfast",
            "year": 2022,
            "people": [
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Merita",
                        "last": "Giraud"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/31.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "merita.giraud@example.com",
                    "age": 27,
                    "score": 9.174597203460992,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4b"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Yolanda",
                        "last": "Thomas"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/1.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "yolanda.thomas@example.com",
                    "age": 50,
                    "score": 9.014386121808409,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4c"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Jorn",
                        "last": "Hakkens"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/49.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "male",
                    "email": "jorn.hakkens@example.com",
                    "age": 47,
                    "score": 8.453602526940033,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4d"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Nils",
                        "last": "Adam"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/9.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "male",
                    "email": "nils.adam@example.com",
                    "age": 53,
                    "score": 7.405307108969225,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4e"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Ceyhan",
                        "last": "Karaduman"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/61.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "ceyhan.karaduman@example.com",
                    "age": 53,
                    "score": 9.79924527946733,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a4f"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Sam",
                        "last": "Mendoza"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/29.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "male",
                    "email": "sam.mendoza@example.com",
                    "age": 50,
                    "score": 8.378680917061923,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a50"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Phyllis",
                        "last": "Pena"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/25.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "phyllis.pena@example.com",
                    "age": 35,
                    "score": 8.463788241672331,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a51"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Jamilla",
                        "last": "Curiel"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/66.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "jamilla.curiel@example.com",
                    "age": 27,
                    "score": 8.595350377144374,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a52"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Natali",
                        "last": "Hoyer"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/17.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "natali.hoyer@example.com",
                    "age": 62,
                    "score": 7.800214827853902,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a53"
                },
                {
                    "name": {
                        "first": "Malou",
                        "last": "Sørensen"
                    },
                    "picture": {
                        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/42.jpg"
                    },
                    "gender": "female",
                    "email": "malou.sorensen@example.com",
                    "age": 67,
                    "score": 9.793432061576496,
                    "_id": "622a2663658a760100143a54"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

My normal find to return the normal non sorted list looks like this:

```
const Event = require("../models/event");

const getEvents = async (req, res) => {
  let result = Event.find();
  const events = await result;
  res.status(200).json({ events });
};

module.exports = {
  getEvents,
};
```

I looked up to some solutions already here but couldn't find an appropriate solution. Like this one: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb)