How to sort in-document array in Kotlin/Java MongoDB Driver
Let's say you have a field (array) in your document, and you want to find a document by _id and get that array sorted by descending or ascending, sort the in-document array in efficient way (not the documents, the items of that array field in the single document)
The way I want to sort is by using a BsonDateTime field (updatedAt) which is there on each item of the array field in the Document
So code like:

private val rooms = database.getCollection<LiveChatRoom>("rooms")

rooms.find(clientUserIdFilter(clientUserId))
                .sort(Sorts.descending("${LiveChatRoom::messages.name}.${ChatMessage::updatedAt.name}")) // For some reason, this will not sort the array in that document, even though I saw some results that use similar code and it work, I checked field key and it's correct
                .projection(Projections.slice(LiveChatRoom::messages.name, skip, limit))
                .singleOrNull()?.messages ?: listOf()


Should not work like expected
I tried and used the official docs of Kotlin MongoDB Driver, it doesn't matter if it Java because the Kotlin one is based on MongoDB Java Driver
I also tried using the aggregation but it's end up completely broken (the code I wrote) and I'm not MongoDB expert (at least for now)
Thank you for your time and efforts.

This might be duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449874/how-to-sort-array-inside-collection-record-in-mongodb
But the question is different driver in completely different language and the answer to that question is not 100% clear to me (at least)
Thank you again.
